# Turn index match statement into Google Script

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, match

I am combining tables from different sheets into one on google sheets. What I am trying to do is set up a function `onedit(e)` may be combined with a loop function to run this

> =index($G$2:$G$8,match($A10&$I$1,arrayformula($B$2:$B$8&$E2:$E8),0),"").

I am new to google script so I have just tried using formulas but the formula updates all cells next to it and what I want is that it matches and stays so that next time `column G` gets updated then the result be added to `B10` instead of rewriting `A10`.  (I1 has formula =today() so that it has a place of reference but if the code can just match with the date then that would be great!)

Here is the link to the sheet if you would like to see what I am talking about. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jviYYhI1V_bL8TMVvijR9vo_7sBFfktbhgblGNcYfrQ/edit?usp=sharing

Column `B2:B8` are drop-downs that are based on the list from `A10:A18` if that makes any difference. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been looking for 3 days and can't find something that would do this.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish, updating `B10:C18`? or updating `A10:A18`?  It's not clear in your question.

Comment: @AMolina What I want to do is for example: When Ana Luz gets a note on Monday Sep 2nd in G2 then that note will be inputted into Ana Luz B10  but when I go again on Sep10 and add a new note for Ana Luz lets say in G7 (because she has played a role as a councelor that week)  I want that note to be inputted into C10 while keeping that first note in B10. I want to do that all the way though G10 (since we meet with them 5 times a term) For all of the people in the list in A10:A18.  Hope that makes sense I know its a little convoluted.

Comment: After reviewing your comment I think I understand better, you want to have the comments for that day according to the meeting. in the rows from 10:18

Comment: Yes that's pretty much! Do you think you could help?@AMolina

Comment: I've been working on it for a bit, but I am writing some code to do it, I'll post it as an answer when ready

Comment: Thank you so much!! Ive been looking around for days but couldn't  find anything so I am extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function autoload() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var meeting = ss.getRange("B2:F8").getValues();
  var targetNames = ss.getRange("A10:A18").getValues();
  var writtingRange = ss.getRange("B10:F18").getValues();
  var updatedUser = targetNames;
  var writtingColumn = -1;
  var coolMatrix;

  for (var i = 0; i < meeting.length; i++) {
    var name = meeting[i][0]
    for (var j = 0; j < targetNames.length; j++) {
      if (targetNames[j][0] == name) {
        for (var z = 0; z < writtingRange[0].length; z++) {
          if (writtingRange[j][z] == '' && writtingColumn < 0) {
            writtingColumn = z;
            break;
          }
        }
        writtingRange[j][writtingColumn] = meeting[i][4];
        updatedUser[j] = true;
      }
    }
  }

  whiteSpaceRemover(writtingRange);
  ss.getRange("B10:F18").setValues(writtingRange);
}

function whiteSpaceRemover(multidimensionalArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < multidimensionalArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < multidimensionalArray[0].length; j++) {
      if (multidimensionalArray[i][j] == '') {
        multidimensionalArray[i].splice(j, 1);
        multidimensionalArray[i].push('');

      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < multidimensionalArray.length; i++) {
    if (multidimensionalArray[i][0] == '') {
      for (var j = 0; j < multidimensionalArray[i].length; j++) {
        if (multidimensionalArray[i][j] != '') {
          whiteSpaceRemover(multidimensionalArray);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return multidimensionalArray;
}
```

Tested this with a copy of your sheet, and it was working well, it sets the correct note next to the name and a '-' if they were not in the meeting, you have to run it manually for now, but it can be assigned to an `onEdit()` if you'd like.

Comment: @Rihco Great to hear it works! Please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved!

Comment: When you say the one you posted, do you mean the formula? and to set it as an `onEdit()` you just need to change the name of the function from `autoload()` to `onEdit()`

Comment: So I posted a formula that will automatically insert the date on column D as an answer but I do not know how to combine both. If I just add it to the bottom and close it off with }} it will only run the date formula and not the one that you posted.

Comment: I also noticed that if I run it on Edit what it does it that if I enter a note on a person it will give me "-"  for the rest of them even if its on the same date. For example I input something for Ana Luz  in G2 then that note is inputted into Ana Luz B10 but when I go to Sabrina her note in G3 it  will be inputed in C11 instead of B11 even if  the meeting is the same day. Would it be possible to add a condition to be inputed in the same row if Column D is "today" or same date??

Comment: @Rihco that's a possibility, however, I would suggest, as a simpler approach, to manually run the code after adding all the notes. alternatively, since the meetings are on given dates, have a timed script that runs on those dates after the meetings and note-adding are done. As for the mixing of the functions you need to have them separate, each is its own thing. You will, however, need to change the name of one of the functions and call it from the other if you want both to run `onEdit()`

Comment: Yes I was messing around with it after i posted that and figured i needed 2 different functions and a button that could run the autoload script. Thing is that if a person does not have a note for the 1st  day but does 2nd day the note posts in cell of C instead of the 1st emptycell in B Would there be any way to add a section that says **see if cell to the left is empty and it is then paste notes there?** Here is the link take a look at AV rotation there's a note showing what I mean https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcXCbahsmGxEFZiRM2EZOggVvgMdEOWlAgeX1vLD4BE/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Ive tried tweeting your script but had no luck. Do you think you could help me figure out how to make it where it sees the cell to the left and if its blank input note there ?

Comment: One thing I don't understand, the columns where the notes are being written at the bottom (`B10:F18`), don't they match the meeting days? meaning that if the first meeting goes by and a person wasn't there the next meeting would be the second meeting?

Comment: No necessarily, I could set up my first meeting with Person X on Sep11 but my first meeting for person Y on Sep 13 I have to keep track how many times I have meet with them

Comment: Oh alright, I had understood that the meeting list was gonna be by date, let me see what I can do.

Comment: any luck @AMolina??

Comment: the edited code works like a charm. Thabk you once again. Sorry it was so convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function onEdit(event) 
    { var timezone = "GMT-5"; var timestamp_format = "MM/dd/yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
    var updateColName = "Student Name"; 
    var timeStampColName = "Date"; 
    var sheet, ss; 
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();//Get the active sheet 
    var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange(); 
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn(); 
    var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sh

eet.getRange(4, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); 
var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1; 
if (dateCol > -1 && index >=5  && index <= 36 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself! 
var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1); 
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); cell.setValue(date); }

function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var meeting = ss.getRange("B2:F37").getValues(); 
  var targetNames = ss.getRange("A38:A90").getValues();
  var writtingRange = ss.getRange("B38:F90").getValues();
  var updatedUser = targetNames;
  var writtingColumn = -1;
  var coolMatrix;

  for(var i = 0; i < meeting.length; i++){ 
    var name = meeting[i][0] 
    for (var j = 0; j < targetNames.length; j++) { 
      if (targetNames[j][0] == name){
        for (var z = 0; z < writtingRange[0].length; z++) { 
          if (writtingRange[j][z] == '' && writtingColumn < 0) { 
            writtingColumn = z; 
            break; 
          }
        }
        writtingRange[j][writtingColumn] = meeting[i][4];
        updatedUser[j] = true; 
      }
    }
  }
  for (var w = 0; enter code here w < writtingRange.length; w++){
    if (writtingRange[w][writtingColumn] == ''){
      writtingRange[w][writtingColumn] = '-';
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("B38:F90").setValues(writtingRange);
}}
```